# Authorization issues when PATCHing mobilePhone, but not other attributes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have an app that uses the User.ReadWrite.All permissions scope to update user properties.  We use the client credential flow (aka: app-only) to auth with the graph for these requests.

Yesterday we found that we could PATCH postalCode for users without issue, however we couldn't PATCH mobilePhone.  We would get `Authorization_RequestDenied`.

E.g. Request:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/myorganization/users/6c778de7-e2d1-4561-9ecf-2f8bdc8b4ebd

{
    "mobilePhone": "+1 33164339301"
}
```

With a valid bearer token in the Authorization header that contains the following payload (i redacted ids for the tenant and app):

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<REDACTED>/",
  "iat": 1520381940,
  "nbf": 1520381940,
  "exp": 1520385840,
  "aio": "<REDACTED>",
  "app_displayname": "<REDACTED>",
  "appid": "<REDACTED>",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/<REDACTED>/",
  "oid": "<REDACTED>",
  "roles": [
    "User.ReadWrite.All"
  ],
  "sub": "<REDACTED>",
  "tid": "<REDACTED>",
  "uti": "<REDACTED>",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "da640831-a28c-4c66-aa74-8eebede64fc7",
      "date": "2018-03-07T00:34:43"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the JWT includes User.ReadWrite.All which requires admin consent and should be able to update user attributes.

However, with the **exact** same JWT I was able to PATCH postalCode.

The user in question does not look like it is synced from on-prem as the following is present on the user:

```
"onPremisesImmutableId": null,
"onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
"onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
"onPremisesSamAccountName": null,
"onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
"onPremisesUserPrincipalName": null,
```

*Side note: (not sure if it helps) but if i PATCH with the current value of mobilePhone i get a 204 response, not a 403.*

Are there other factors that would preclude mobilePhone from being PATCHed?

**UPDATE:** This was a confirmed bug by the graph team and has now been fixed. You should now be able to patch mobilePhone properly.